# UDP based clients in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, multithreading, udp

I have a server (Developed in Nodejs)communicating with 100s of remote devices on UDP. I want to benchmark it. For that purpose I need to create several UDP clients communicating with the server per second basis. Since multi threading isn't possible in Nodejs, so how can I achieve this? can anybody give me some sort of solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Multi threading isn't possible in Nodejs

That isn't right. It is right that our main event loop within nodejs is only single threaded, but whenever an asynchronous function is called with a callback function, you have a additional thread that runs that I/O network stuff. If this is finished your callback method will be called and it goes back to the main event loop (simply said). So to create several UDP clients and let them fire and stress the UPD server should be no problem, due to the fact that `client.send` is asynchronous. To run them in parallel you can use the module `async`.

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const async = require('async');

async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        var client1 = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
        client1.send("hello", 41234, 'localhost', function(err) {
          client1.close();
          callback();
        });
    },
    function(callback) {
        var client2 = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
        client2.send("world", 41234, 'localhost', function(err) {
          client2.close();
          callback();
        });
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results) {
  // I am done here...
  process.exit();
});
```

or you can just do this

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
var client1 = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
var client2 = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

// This also runs in parallel
client1.send("hello", 41234, 'localhost', function(err) {
    client1.close();
});
client2.send("world", 41234, 'localhost', function(err) {
    client2.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, I wan wandering around on different pages, didnt get what I needed...